# PHP MySQL Printing User Field from Joined Table

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I almost have this but cannot figure out the last step! From two tables I have matched up `post_id` with `username`, so now I just want to print the name of the user under the title of the post with the loop below. The `$joined` query generates the below table... but how do I match the specific user to the post? Let me know if more clarification is needed

```
function get_joined()
{
    $sql = "SELECT `posts`.`post_id` AS `post_id`, 
        `posts`.`post_date` AS `post_date`, 
        `posts`.`post_title` AS `post_title`, 
        `posts`.`post_body` AS `post_body`,
        `users`.`id` AS `user_id`, 
        `users`.`username` AS `user_name`
 FROM `posts`
LEFT JOIN `users` ON `users`.`id` = `posts`.`user_id`
ORDER BY `post_date` DESC"; 
$joined = mysql_query($sql);

return $joined;
}
```

Printing the post, my issue is at `<?php echo $joined['username']; ?>`

```
<?php

    $posts = get_posts();
    foreach($posts as $post)
    {
        ?>

    <h2><a href ="blog_read.php?pid=<?php echo $post['id']; ?>"><?php echo   $post['title']; ?></a></h2>
    <h4>By <font color="#FF6347"><?php echo $posts['user_name']; ?></a></font> on <?php echo $post['date']; ?></h4> 
    <h4><?php echo $post['total_comments']; ?> comments, last comment <?php echo $post['last_comment']; ?>
    <hr />

    <p><?php echo $post['preview']; ?>...</p>
    <?php

}

?>
```

Users Table:
    `id|username`
     `1  |  steve`
     `2  |     jon`
     `3  |    mike` etc

Posts Table:
    `post_id|post_user|post_tite|post_body|post_date`
     `1  |  steve`      `title`     `body`              `date`
     `2  |    steve`      `title`     `body`              `date`
     `3  |    steve`      `title`     `body`              `date`
 etc

Comment: Is `get_joined()` supposed to return all posts? All it does it return one random post ID and the user who posted it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `get_posts` function should be joining the username into `$posts`, probably via an SQL `JOIN` join... Otherwise, your indexes will not be correct and you will get usernames displaying on posts that don't belong there (the orders will be wrong).

An example SQL:

```
SELECT
  posts.id AS post_id,
  posts.date AS post_date,
  posts.title AS post_title,
  posts.content AS post_content,
  users.id AS user_id,
  users.username AS user_name
FROM
  posts
LEFT JOIN
  users ON users.id = posts.user_id
ORDER BY
  post_date DESC # newest first
```

Comment: So with that new table, can i keep the `<?php echo $joined['username']; ?>` the same? Or is there a way I can select the correct post from this newly ordered list?

Comment: Depends whatever variable name you use. This alleviates the use of having two queries. So `$posts` would contain your `username` key, and could be accessed via `$posts['user_name']`, for example..

Comment: I think `LEFT JOIN` is better here. Because if a user never publish a post it will return a null entry.

Comment: @netsmertia agreed: just thought of this as well. updated answer.

Comment: I am still getting the error that `user_name` is undefined. Updated code above.

Comment: @stmyd: my example is for EXAMPLE only, it does not take your current database setup into consideration. You will need to rewrite it using your own table and column names! You should never edit questions based on someones answer, either. I've reverted.

Comment: I did not take it right off, i have adapted it on my end, and the error is relative unfortunately. All i need to do is match the post with the user.

Comment: You're using `$posts` not `$post`

Comment: I already made that adjustment and nothing changed unfortunately, still the error

Comment: Modify your question to include the table structure of your posts and users tables along with relationships

Comment: Just to clarify, doing `posts[user_name]' should return the most recent author correct? and therfore make the correct match?

Comment: Without knowing your DB structure, we can not help.

Comment: If you have the post_user in the posts table like that already, then what's the need for a users table? Your database design is flawed.

Comment: sorry i felt it was irrelevant but the users table also has fields such as password email etc.